Google Places Autocomplete API returning "The Places API server returned a response we couldn't understand" (Error Code -2)
I'm using the Google Places API in my iOS app to fetch autocomplete suggestions for places within a specific geographical region. However, I'm receiving an error, and I haven't been able to resolve it. Here's the code I'm using:
func searchPlaces(query: String) {
    guard !query.isEmpty else {
        self.querylocations = []
        return
    }

    let token = GMSAutocompleteSessionToken()

    let northWestBounds = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.921628, -73.700051)
    let southEastBounds = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.477398, -74.259087)

    let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
    filter.types = [kGMSPlaceTypeRestaurant]
    filter.locationBias = GMSPlaceRectangularLocationOption(northWestBounds, southEastBounds)

    let request = GMSAutocompleteRequest(query: query)
    request.filter = filter
    request.sessionToken = token

    GMSPlacesClient.shared().fetchAutocompleteSuggestions(from: request, callback: { ( results, error ) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Autocomplete error: \(error)")
            return
        }
        if let autocompleteResults = results {
            for result in autocompleteResults {
                if let place = result.placeSuggestion {
                    self.querylocations.append(Place(name: place.attributedFullText.string,
                                                     coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(),
                                                     id: place.placeID))
                }
            }
        }
    })
}

I'm encountering the following error:

Autocomplete error: Error Domain=com.google.places.ErrorDomain Code=-2 "The Places API server returned a response that we couldn't understand. If you believe this error represents a bug, please file a report using the instructions on our community and support page (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/support)." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The Places API server returned a response that we couldn't understand. If you believe this error represents a bug, please file a report using the instructions on our community and support page (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/support)., NSUnderlyingError=0x600000e10ed0 {Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=403 "Internal Error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Internal Error}}}

After reviewing the Google Places API documentation, I found that this is an error related to internal server issues, but I would like to know if anyone has experienced this issue and how it might be resolved.
What I have checked:
My API key is correct and properly configured.
I have ensured that the Places API is enabled in my Google Cloud Console.
I have checked my API usage quotas and haven't exceeded them.
Familiarity with billing: I've made sure billing is active and associated with my project.
Has anyone encountered this before or have any ideas on how to fix this issue?

You have a 403 response, so something isn't correct in your authentication.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=(query)&key=(Configuration.googleMapsApiKey)
The situation is that when I use the Google Places API, I keep experiencing this issue. However, when I make a direct request to the link I shared, I receive a successful response. This makes me think there might be a bug in the library.

This solution worked for me, https://stackoverflow.com/a/79163878/15023395
